# Regarding primary key of one table to act as a foreign key in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables named EMPLOYEE and DEPARTMENT as follows:

```
CREATE table "EMPLOYEE" (
    "EMP_ID"     NUMBER,
    "ENAME"      VARCHAR2(4000),
    "SALARY"     VARCHAR2(4000),
    "COMPANY"    VARCHAR2(4000),
    "CONTACTNO." NUMBER,
    "GENDER"     CHAR(100),
    constraint  "EMPLOYEE_PK" primary key ("EMP_ID")
)

CREATE TABLE  "DEPARTMENT" 
(   
    "DEPT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "DEPT_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "LOCATION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "CONTACTNO." NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "DEPARTMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPT_ID") ENABLE
)
```

Now I am trying to make Emp_ID of EMPLOYEE table as primary key in EMPLOYEE table itself but it should act as a foreign key for DEPT_ID in DEPARTMENT table, please advise how to achieve this!

Comment: Presumably, this is a made-up example, right?  It wouldn't make sense for there to be a foreign key relationship between the `EMP_ID` column in `EMPLOYEE` and the `DEPT_ID` column in `DEPARTMENT`.  If you really had these two tables, you would want to add a `DEPT_ID` column to `EMPLOYEE` that references the `DEPT_ID` of `DEPARTMENT`. Assuming this is a made-up example, do you want the `EMPLOYEE` to be the parent or the child table in the foreign key relationship?

Comment: Why you should not  have the department_id in the employee table ?

Comment: @JustinCave Employee to be parent table and it should reference as DEPARTMENT table

Comment: @RockySinha - The child table references the parent table.  If `EMPLOYEE` is the parent, the foreign key must be created on the `DEPARTMENT` table and `DEPARTMENT` must reference `EMPLOYEE`.

Comment: You need to add an `dept_id` column to `employee`. Only then you can create a FK from dept to emp that makes sense.

Comment: These are just two random tables.  They have no common columns which can act as anchor points in a foreign key relationship.  So add DEPT_NO to EMPLOYEE (which makes more sense than adding EMP_ID to DEPARTMENT) and then you have a proper question.  Although one which is still trivial to answer for yourself by reading the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#i1036780

Answer (score 2):

If `EMPLOYEE` is to be the parent table and `DEPARTMENT` is to be the child table, the foreign key would need to be defined on `DEPARTMENT` where it references the `EMP_ID` in the `EMPLOYEE` table.  The foreign key is created on the child table and references the parent table.

```
CREATE TABLE  "DEPARTMENT" 
(   
    "DEPT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "DEPT_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "LOCATION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "CONTACTNO." NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "DEPARTMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPT_ID") ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT department_fk FOREIGN KEY( DEPT_ID )
       REFERENCES employee( EMP_ID )
)
```

Of course, given your example, defining the foreign key constraint would be a completely incorrect approach to modeling the data.  It makes no sense for the set of valid department IDs to be constrained by the set of employee IDs.  Defining the foreign key this way also prevents a department from ever having more than 1 employee.  If you were really modelling departments and employees, you would add a `DEPT_ID` column to the `EMPLOYEE` table, the `EMPLOYEE` table would be the child, not the parent, and the foreign key would be defined on the `EMPLOYEE` table to reference the `DEPARTMENT` table.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could help you

```
CREATE table "EMPLOYEE" (
"EMP_ID"     NUMBER,
"ENAME"      VARCHAR2(4000),
"SALARY"     VARCHAR2(4000),
"COMPANY"    VARCHAR2(4000),
"Dept_id"    NUMBER,
"CONTACTNO." NUMBER,
"GENDER"     CHAR(100),
 constraint  "EMPLOYEE_PK" primary key ("EMP_ID"),
 CONSTRAINT fk_DeptId FOREIGN KEY (Dept_Id)
 REFERENCES Department("Dept_Id") 
);
```

Comment: Thanks  lot dude but getting this error ..ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis ..upon executing on oracle 10g express edition

Comment: @Rocky Sinha Find it now, i have missed the , between the constraint it should work fine

Comment: It won't work fine. You're quoting everything... you should avoid this if at all possible: `Dept_Id == DEPT_ID != "Dept_Id"`

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE table "EMPLOYEE" (
    "EMP_ID"     NUMBER,
    "ENAME"      VARCHAR2(4000),
    "SALARY"     VARCHAR2(4000),
    "COMPANY"    VARCHAR2(4000),
    "CONTACTNO"  NUMBER,
    "GENDER"     CHAR(100),
    constraint  "EMPLOYEE_PK" primary key ("EMP_ID")
)


ALTER TABLE "EMPLOYEE" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEE_FK" 
FOREIGN KEY ("EMP_ID")
REFERENCES "DEPARTMENT" ("DEPT_ID")
```

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense for EMP_ID to reference DEPT_ID.

Comment: While it is possible to create a constraint which requires that the EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID column contain a value which exists in the DEPARTMENT.DEPT_ID column, to my eye this is fundamentally incorrect. Put in words this says, "The ID of an employee must equal the ID of a department". Given that EMP_ID is the primary key on EMPLOYEE, this means that each EMPLOYEE must exist in its own department, and department and an employee are, in effect, synonyms.